# What does it mean "to be projected into your life" in this text?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am an easy going and laid back person, I love life and try to live to the fullest. One of my favorite activities is to smile and make people laugh, I feel there is so much negativity **being projected into our lives** that I want to bring happiness and light. There is so much that this life has to offer and I have chosen to be happy in it and be grateful for all the blessings that have been bestowed upon me. I lead my own experience and don't follow trends and/or people. I am an ambitious person and I believe I can have it all love, family, friendship and a career and I want someone who shares that same view and who encourages my success, as will I with them and not be intimidated by it.

Comment: Where is this text from?

Comment: A girl on her blog

Comment: "projected" in the sense of unavoidable: TV, newspapers, bad attitudes, gossip (often negative), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In a cinema the images [on the film] are projected onto the screen.  They are made larger, brighter than anything else, and we can't help it but be under their influence.  The author speaks of the similar action, negative images are being projected onto our lives like on the cinema screen, brought to our attention, made very bright and large...

I am not sure but I think it is an allegory.